# Jhipster : issue with yarn start task on CommonsChunkPlugin.js

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg

I have upgraded to Jhipster 4.7.2.
When I run `yarn start`,
I am getting :

```
> home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js:296
>           for(const module of chunk.modulesIterable) {
>                           ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
>     at usedChunks.reduce (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js:296:27)
>     at Array.reduce (native)
>     at CommonsChunkPlugin.getExtractableModules (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js:295:46)
>     at targetChunks.forEach (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js:136:38)
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at Compilation.compilation.plugin (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js:102:18)
>     at Compilation.applyPluginsBailResult1 (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:122:27)
>     at Compilation.seal (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:571:9)
>     at /home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:488:16
>     at /home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:271:11
>     at _addModuleChain (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:477:11)
>     at processModuleDependencies.err (/home/myPc/dev/workspace/myApp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:448:13)
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Do you know where  that issue comes from?

Comment: Which version of node do you use? We recommend an LTS version (currently 6.x). Latest version of Jhipster is currently 4.7.0, so I guess you're using 4.6.2. Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: I am using 6.11.0. Doing a npm install webpack-dev-server
solved the problem

Comment: You should avoid mixing yarn and npm